# Problem with Mingw even with setting paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image]

I've been trying to setup C++ on my laptop. I've installed Mingw and the packages. I have the bin path (`C:\MinGW\bin`) in Path location. I've tried both Path user and system but I still get `g++ is not recognized` in command prompt. In the terminal of Visual Studio Code, I run `g++ --version`, I get the correct response. But when running a program, it'll say `g++ is not recognized`.

CMD PATH
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Windows\System32\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\Wbem;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\system32\OpenSSH;C:\MinGW\bin;

PowerShell
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Windows\System32\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\Wbem;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\system32\OpenSSH;C:\MinGW\bin;

EDIT: gcc and g++ only work when I do gcc.exe --version or g++.exe --version. This causes problem with visual studio code because when trying to run the program, it's running with just gcc instead of gcc.exe.

Comment: Side note: If you ever find yourself juggling multiple compilers you may come to regret having built one into the path.

Comment: That said, could you add the full and complete path string to the question? If it's some thing simple like a typo or missing delimiter we'll be able to knock that out very quickly. You can easily get the path by typing path into a cmd window.

Comment: Shouldn't "C:\MinGW\bin" be the path string used? It has all the gcc.exe and g++.exe files.

Comment: You may need to tell VS Code to use `g++`. Have a look at this link about setting `compilerPath`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_compiler-path

Comment: What about cmd not able to run g++ --version?

Comment: I'm looking for the full system path that the command prompt is going to use for look-up. It should contain a LOT more than just the location of mingw. A typo anywhere in the string could wreck havoc.

Comment: You know how I can find it?

Comment: From Windows cmd: `echo %PATH%`. From Mingw terminal: `echo $PATH`.

Comment: I've included a picture of the system path in the post. I also recently added the different "C:\Windows paths into the system, because my pc has those and is working.

Comment: And for compliler path in visual studio code, I can't seem to find the file that is in the post. Mine looks like this "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"

Comment: You have a bunch of stuff repeated in there, but other than that looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of things that can cause that

First, make sure that you installed MinGW probably as shown in this picture:
[image: 1]

second, make sure that in `C:\MinGW\bin` `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe` are located and working probably (run them from the cmd in the same folder)

after that close the cmd if it's opened and try to type gcc or g++

and if it didn't work you can check the `PATH` by typing `echo %PATH%`
and you `C:\MinGW\bin` separated by a semicolon

Comment: cmd in the bin folder?

Comment: yeah just open it there 
by shift+right click
or by typing cmd in the directory bar

Comment: I opened a powershell terminal and ran gcc --version and it worked. But cmd still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any chance my cmd is broken or path is incorrect? Nothing seem to be working for PATH.

Comment: can you please send you PATH
by using
`echo %PATH%` (for cmd), `$env:Path` (for powershell)

Comment: and make sure that cmd works probobly by using commands like `cd` or `dir` or `ipconfig`

Comment: Just posted them for this post underneath.

Comment: there's three `MinGW/bin` in your path 
so i guess that's the problem
so pls edit to be only one 
or you can copy and paste this:

Comment: CMD is still not working after editing the PATH to one MinGW/bin.

Comment: I ran gcc.exe --version in cmd and it worked

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are doing so to get g++ compiler. And in case you are unable to rectify the problem you can do following:

1. First of all, install Windows Subsystem for LInux on Windows Features. Reboot.
2. Install Ubuntu.
3. Run bash and create a user account with a password.
4. Make a “sudo apt update” to update the repo packages.
5. Then you can do “sudo apt install gcc” and “sudo apt install g++”.
6. Use Remote wsl on VS.
7. Mnt your files on wsl

Comment: he's using windows

Comment: @Titoot that's why  I mentioned WSL(windows subsystem for Linux), windows included it to let developer run a GNU/Linux environment — including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications — directly on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the problem was my PATHEXT the whole time. I must have enter a new pathext variable a while ago for some reason and it messed it all up.